# Getting the network interface name with InterfaceByName in Windows

Tags: windows, go, winpcap

I'm trying to use this [code](https://github.com/hellojukay/arp-scanner) to perform an ARP Scan. But when choosing my interface in Windows ("Ethernet").

I'm getting the following error :

```
interface Ethernet: Ethernet: Error opening adapter ...
```

I've tried with `-iface "\Device\NPF_{90C99FE1-3902-4DF4-8710-05539D4A7578}"`

But I'm getting the following error :

`can not get interface \Device\NPF_{90C99FE1-3902-4DF4-8710-05539D4A7578}, route ip+net: no such network interface`

Can someone please help with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to replace the name of the interface in :  `pcap.OpenLive`